# ErrorException: Object of class Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator could not be converted to string - October CMS

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I'm working on a website that I did not build. This website is built on October CMS platform. I'm currently trying to add a new page to this website but, whenever I try to view the page, I get a 500 server error on the front-end, and when I look at the event logs, I see this error:

**ErrorException: Object of class Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator could not be converted to string**

This website has a custom plugin and custom theme built for it. I've been digging through routing files and controllers and am not sure where to look, since I am not too familiar with October CMS or Laravel.

Could this be related to custom routes set up in the custom theme/plugin? When creating a new page, am I supposed to adjust the routes in some way?

I'm sorry that this question is a little vague, but I'm honestly at a loss and am looking for some direction on where to even start to solve this issue.

I'm happy to provide code examples, if that's necessary.

Thank you!!

Comment: You can do one thing you can disable one by one plugin and check may be they are interfering in routes... and find the plugin which is causing issue .